# Recreating images from arrays

Tags: vb.net, image, image-processing, grayscale

I have an array of integers from 0 to 255 representing the gray scale array.
I want to display that array as an image.
This  my_array looks like this :
...
26
33
56
90
123
157
181
188
197
198
...

I was trying :

```
    Dim imgNew As Image
    Dim bytes() As Byte
    bytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(my_array.ToString)

    Dim memImage As New System.IO.MemoryStream(bytes)
    imgNew = Image.FromStream(memImage)

    Dim pav As Bitmap = imgNew
    PictureBox1.Image = pav
```

But it does not work.

Ok I managed to draw an image according to my grayscale array(my_array):

```
    Dim pav As New Bitmap("opens_white_image_of_resolution_height_x_width")

    Dim ix
    Dim iy
    For iy = 0 To pav.height-1
        For ix = 0 To pav.Width - 1
            pav.SetPixel(ix, iy, Color.FromArgb(250, my_array(pixl), my_array(pixl), my_array(pixl)))
            pixl += 1
        Next
    Next
    g.DrawImage(pav, 0, 0, pav.Width, pav.Height)
    pav.Save("savefoldername", ImageFormat.Jpeg)
```

The problem is I have to open blank image 'pav' from C disk and then set pixels into it.

I want to skip that step of creating manually that image. How can I do it?

Comment: in order for `imgNew = Image.FromStream(memImage)` to do anything, the bytes in the stream have to actually BE from an image.  you cant get a valid bitmap from random bytes.

Comment: Are you working in [Processing](http://processing.org/)?

Comment: I am not working with Processing... So is there a way to recreate an image from gray scale array?